# Where is "apt-cache search"?

Tags: command-line, apt, software-center, software-sources

Wish to search apt repositories with CLI tool. Did that in the past with:

```
apt-cache search <search_term>
```

Don't find apt-cache package:

```
# apt-get install apt-cache
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apt-cache
```

Enabled all default repositories (multiverse).

Answer (score 5):

You got the reported result for
`apt-get install apt-cache` because there is no package called `apt-cache`.
The following commands are part of `apt` package:
`apt-cache, apt-cdrom, apt-config, apt-get, apt-key, apt-mark`
**Courtesy:** Ubuntu software center

Since `apt-get` itself is working for you, the `apt` package and therefore `apt-cache` command should be installed in your system. So no need for manually installing it.

Try `apt-cache show apt` to ensure that your `apt-cache` command is working.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the reason you wont find apt-cache for installation is because its supposed to be part of apt.

Perhaps a reinstall of apt would be in order?
Something like this:
http://www.ehow.com/how_8141696_reinstall-apt-ubuntu.html